# tcp клиент не корректные данные

Tags: c++, сеть, сокет, tcp

Набросал такой вот tcp клиент

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    WSAData wsaData;
    WORD DLLVersion = MAKEWORD(2, 1);
    std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
     if(WSAStartup(DLLVersion, &wsaData) != 0){
        std::cout <<"errror" <<std::endl;
        exit(1);
     }
     SOCKADDR_IN addr;
     int sizeofaddr = sizeof(addr);
     addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "192.168.0.106");
     addr.sin_port = htons(4444);
     addr.sin_family = AF_INET;


     SOCKET Connection = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

     if (connect(Connection, (SOCKADDR*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
         std::cout << "Error: failed connect to server.\n";
         return 1;
     }
     std::cout << "Connected!\n";
     char msg[256];
     char m[256] = "tilox";
     send(Connection, m, sizeof(m), 0);

     while (1) {

         recv(Connection, msg, sizeof(msg), 0);

         std::cout << msg << std::endl;
     }
    return 0;
}
```

Данные с сервера приходят
но через какое то время время данные эм.. объединяются с прошлыми данными
вот к примеру сервер прислал `1` 
пришло

```
1
3
x
```

3 x - информация с прошлых сообщений
Как я понимаю проблема в том, что переменная msg не отчищается перед получением информации
я сделал так msg = ""; но что то не помогло..

Comment: Нет, проблема в том, что вы игнорируете значение, возвращаемое `recv` и прочими C функциями

Comment: Не совсем понимаю что что надо исправить ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что `operator<<(ostream&, const char*)` ожидает нуль-терминированную строку, в то время как `recv()` принимает сырые данные и не записывает завершающий `0` в конец буфера. На практике цикл чтения должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
while (1) {
    ssize_t count = recv(Connection, msg, sizeof(msg)-1, 0);
    if (count==0) {
      break;
    } else if (count < 0) {
      std::cerr << "recv() failed" << std::endl;
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    msg[count] = 0;
    std::cout << msg << std::endl;
}
```